# can't call method within render block? - trying to extract repetitive page.replace_html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `generate_drawer_data' for #):

caused when the method call is in the block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :update do |page|
      generate_drawer_data(page)
```

but when the method is outside the block, no runtime errors:

```
generate_drawer_data()

respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :update do |page|
```

the method, near the bottom of the controller

```
 def generate_drawer_data(page = false)
   ... page_replaces
    end
```

So... why am I getting this behavior?

I'm using ruby on rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that block passed to `render :update` is more like a view, so it has access to controller's instance variable and helpers. Try define this method as helper method using `helper_method :generate_drawer_data`.